# Console output omitted when using commas instead of "\n"

Tags: c, printf, newline

I can't explain myself the following weird behaviour:

In the `inOrder()` function, if I write `printf("%d\n", node->value)` (hence with `"\n"`)everything works fine and the program gives the following output:

```
5
8
10
Printing Tree.
8,5,10,5
8
10
```

If I write `printf("%d,", node->value)` (hence just with a "`,`" instead of "`\n`") the program gives me only the following output.

```
5,8,10,Printing Tree.
```

As you can see, the values of the tree aren't printed and neither are they printed in the repeated inOrder traversal.

Do you have an explanation for this behaviour? Does this have to do with the combined usage of `puts()` and `printf()` on the same line? Does `puts()` maybe add a character that indicates the end of a string?

(I'm using Xcode)

Here's the complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

void printTree(Node *root)
{
    puts("Printing Tree.");
    printf("%d,", root->value);
    printf("%d,", root->left->value);
    printf("%d,", root->right->value);
}

void inOrder(Node *node)
{
    if(node!=NULL)
    {
        inOrder(node->left);
        printf("%d,", node->value);
        inOrder(node->right);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Node a = {10, NULL};
    Node b = {5, NULL};
    Node root = {8, &b, &a};

    inOrder(&root);

    printTree(&root);

    inOrder(&root);
}
```

Comment: Output to `stdout` is *line buffered,* this means, that output is only sent to the console once a full line is to be printed. Try to add an `fflush(stdout)` after you print to see if this is the problem.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.   it raises some 8 warnings.  Those warnings need to be fixed.  Suggest compiling with all warnings enabled.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')

Comment: there are 3 fields in each node.  The posted code is only initializing the first 2 fields.  I.E. the third field contains trash, (probably not NULL) .  Suggest correcting the node initialization statements.   The two parameters to the main() function are not used.  suggest declaring main as: 'int main( void )'.  To avoid returning garbage to the OS, suggest inserting a 'return 0;' statement just before the final closing brace ';}'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point to notice here is, the standard output is line buffered. When you call `printf()` without a `newline`, the data to be sent to the standard output is sent to the output buffer, but not immediately *flushed* to the output screen.

A `\n` helps to *flush* the buffer to the output screen *immediately*.

Alternatively, you can use `fflush(stdout)` to make the buffer flush manually.

Answer (score 2):

`stdout` output is buffered on `\n`.

Either print a final `\n` or disable the buffering with

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```